# Make the close votes queue side by side

Tags: feature-request, review

On the "Close Votes" review queue, if a question is flagged as a duplicate, can we show the items in question side by side like we do with "Suggested Edits"? Currently, we use a tab system, and switching back and forth is quite annoying.

It isn't natural really. When I'm comparing two text documents, I launch another instance of Notepad++ instead of using the tabs. I then snap the two windows to the side of the screen.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate feature-request, but it hasn't been implemented yet so it gets my +1 anyway. =D

Comment: You have enough real-estate on your mobile device to be able to read a side-by-side layout?  I guess you mean a tablet and not a phone.

Comment: @JSteen Not that I'm aware of. I've searched twice and couldn't find anything.

Comment: @MonicaCellio No, it's a phone. It just zooms out. The review queue is a desktop page, not mobile optimized.

Comment: what should happen when there's more than one duplicate candidate?

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter I have yet to experience that. In that case, tabs would be ok